# Default ListViews in Lightning

Tags: list-view, lightning-experience

Is there a way to give a profile a different default list view then "Recently Viewed" in Lightning?

Comment: Despite of @Anthony McQueen finding I suggest to vote for this idea about customizing default list view - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cM0fQAE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From this [Salesforce help page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=lex_gaps_limitations_data_access.htm&language=en_US), the answer appears to be "no":

> List views display and behave differently in Lightning Experience.
>
> - You don’t go to a new page to create a list view. Instead, you stay on the same page and give the list view a name in a pop-up dialog box. You add filters to customize your list with a panel that slides out on the right side of the page.
> - You can only restrict list views by selecting All or My. Other options, such as restricting by queue, campaign, or price book, aren’t available.
> - Navigation through list views has changed. Because list views have infinite scrolling, you can’t specify the number of records to show per page. Also, you can’t navigate through pages with arrow buttons, and you can’t jump to a specific page of results. Jumping to records with names that start with a particular letter isn’t available.
> - The drop-down menu shows up to 2000 views. The menu loads views in batches of 50 as you scroll down. Recently viewed lists appear first, followed by other list views in alphabetical order. Recently viewed lists and the Search box appear only if there are 11 or more list views.
> - You can’t change the order of columns by dragging the column heading to a new position in the table. Instead, you change the columns that appear and their order by choosing Select Fields to Display from the List View Controls drop-down menu. If you add or remove a column in Lightning Experience, all custom column widths are deleted. You can switch back to Salesforce Classic to adjust column widths.
> - Limited row-level actions are available. For most objects, available actions are Edit and Delete. For leads, two more actions are available: Convert and Clone. For files, available actions are Edit, Delete, and Download.
> - Custom buttons are available, but can’t be configured to do record action or mass actions like mass edit or mass delete. For example an admin can create a button that launches a Visualforce page.
> - For filter criteria, only these relative date ranges are supported: Today, Tomorrow, Yesterday, This Week, This Month, This Quarter, This Year, Last Week, Last Month, Last Quarter, Last Year.
> - List views in Lightning Experience don’t support starts with as a filter criterion for ID fields. An ID field is a 15-character field that identifies a record. For example, the Account ID field on the contact object identifies which account a contact is associated with. You can use starts with as a filter criterion for other fields.
> - In filter logic statements, NOT doesn’t work with parenthetical expressions. For example, the expression 1 AND NOT (2 AND 3) evaluates as 1 AND (NOT 2 AND 3). In the filter results, no records are returned when you’d expect to see some records.
> - Filters support values only between the minimum and maximum for a signed 23-bit integer, or between 1 and 2,147,483,648. A value outside of this range disables that filter.
> - **The name of the recent records list that displays on the home page for every standard and custom object is different in Lightning Experience. It’s called Recently Viewed. This view isn’t deletable, filterable, or editable. Salesforce admins can use the Object Manager in Setup to select and order columns for this view. Your users can sort items in the view by clicking inside a column header. An arrow in the column header shows if the list items are sorted in ascending or descending order.**
> - Another list view is available for most standard objects via the drop-down list with a name similar to Recently Viewed. The name of this view includes the name of the object. For example, this list view for accounts is called Recently Viewed Accounts. These two list views, Recently Viewed and Recently Viewed Objects, show the same records. The Recently Viewed Objects list view isn’t deletable, filterable, or editable. Your users can sort the records and chart this list view’s data. They can switch to Salesforce Classic to reorder the columns displayed in the list view. The columns appear in the new order when the user switches back to Lightning Experience.

Comment: That's what I thought based on my research, but I wanted to see if anyone else had any luck finding anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can also choose a view from the dropdown next to the tab in Winter 17'. Took my team a bit to notice!

[image]

Comment: This is a good finding!

Answer (score 0):

For Salesforce Communities Users:

Go into Lightning Community builder to your desired community site and select "Navigation Menu".

Then select/create a new menu item with "Salesforce Object" as type.

You will then see a new drop-down below that allows you to choose the "Default List View", allowing to change it from "Recently viewed".